# django 1.5 create project - ImportError: cannot import name total_ordering

Tags: django

I'm totally newby in django

When i try run "django-admin.py startproject mysite" command i've got this error messages:

lib/python3.1/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 349, in 
    from functools import total_ordering
ImportError: cannot import name total_ordering

I use virtualenv and django 1.5b2

what should i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You should update to at least Python 3.2.](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.total_ordering)

> *New in version 3.2.*